# CSS style padding with em and px

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to do padding with pixels and em?  So for instance, can I add `padding-left` by 2em plus 1px?  Something like this...

```
padding-left: 2em + 1px;
```

Comment: you can't...... instead doing the following may solve your problem: `padding-left: 2em` and `margin-left: 1px` or vice versa.

Comment: No you can not do this..

Comment: You can use something like [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/#usage), but that may be a bit much for what you want.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for the `calc` expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

for example:

```
padding: -webkit-calc(2em + 1px);
padding: calc(2em + 1px);
```

Be warned, (at the time of writing) this property is still considered experimental. You may want to check [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/calc) to see if this expression will work in all browsers you are developing for.

Comment: Just a note: make sure you leave spaces between the values and the `+`.

Comment: some extra links : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc , http://caniuse.com/calc :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div id="el">asdfasd</div>
```

---

```
#el {
    background-color:green;
    padding-left: 2em;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/SWrfL/4/)

Comment: why are you using absolute positioning? why not just simply have the parent use `padding-left: 1px` and the child use `padding-left: 2em` (or vice versa)? absolute positioning is not what you want for this situation.

Comment: @uber5001 you are giving `padding-left: 1px;` to the parent element. I am just stretching the child element and making necessary adjustments using parent element.

Comment: This doesn't even work. I tried your fiddle. I added text into the child div. The child doesn't even have padding; the box just appears wider. You've stretched the child over the parent, effectively removing the padding effect. The effect is that the width is increased by 2em+1px, rather than adding padding.

Comment: one last, super-picky thing: Why not just use `padding-left: 1px;` in the `#parent` rather than `margin-left: 1px` in the `#child`? The question _does_ ask for padding, not margin. =)

Comment: @uber5001 haha does the same trick. You can say that I am just focussing more on child element. :) (Actually, there is no need of parent element here, it is just for showing that there exist `1px` dummy padding too)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31751/discussion-between-uber5001-and-mr-green)